# pandas split column by some specific words and keep this delimiter

Tags: python, pandas

I want to split the column by some specific words and keep the delimiter in the same time. I tried to split the column with `str.split` but the result isn't I want.

example data(test.csv):

```
a
abc123and321abcor213cba
abc321or123cbaand321cba
```

my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df[['b','c']] = df['a'].str.split("and",1,expand=True)
df[['c','d']] = df['c'].str.split("or",1,expand=True)
print(df)
```

my result:

```
                         a               b       c       d
0  abc123and321abcor213cba          abc123  321abc  213cba
1  abc321or123cbaand321cba  abc321or123cba  321cba    None
```

Desired result:

```
                         a               b         c       d
0  abc123and321abcor213cba       abc123and  321abcor  213cba
1  abc321or123cbaand321cba        abc321or 123cbaand  321cba
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Borrowing from Tim's answer using a lookbehind Regex to split on `and` or `or`, without using up the seperating string in the split:

```
d = {'a': ["abc123and321abcor213cba", "abc321or123cbaand321cba"]}

df = pandas.DataFrame(data=d)

df[["b", "c", "d"]] = df['a'].str.split(r'(?<=and)|(?<=or)', expand=True)
```

Output:

```
                         a          b          c       d
0  abc123and321abcor213cba  abc123and   321abcor  213cba
1  abc321or123cbaand321cba   abc321or  123cbaand  321cba
```

Comment: Thank you! but I don't know why I only get the ```valueError:split() requires a non-empty pattern match``` .  Is this a version problem?  I am python3.6 and pandas 1.1.5

Comment: Are you trying on only the test data you provided or a bigger dataset? I have no issues with Python 3.9.9, but I know Pandas string splitting has been changed.

Comment: I can replicate your issue on Python 3.6.0 only. After some digging it seems there was a bug (or maybe kind of a feature?) in that version that didn't let the `.split()` method work on matches that had no length. https://bugs.python.org/issue43222

Comment: oh I see. This means I should update my python version. Thank you~

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting on the lookbehind `(?<=and|or)`:

```py
df[['b', 'c', 'd']] = df['a'].str.split(r'(?<=and)|(?<=or)', 1, expand=True)
```

Comment: I just try this and get a error ```look-behind requires fixed-width pattern```

Comment: Try using this line instead: `df = df['a'].str.split(r'(?<=and)|(?<=or)', expand=True)` @Teemo

Comment: I get another error ```split() requires a non-empty pattern match ``` 
@ChristyKail

Comment: @Teemo see updated answer

Answer (score 1):

If you have issues with `split` check that you don't have a too old pandas version.

You could also use `str.extractall` and `unstack`. I'll also recommend to use`join` to add the columns if you don't know in advance the number of matches/columns?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ["abc123and321abcor213cba", "abc321or123cbaand321cba"]})

df.join(df['a'].str.extractall(r'(.*?(?:and|or)|.+$)')[0].unstack('match'))
```

Output:

```
                         a          0          1       2
0  abc123and321abcor213cba  abc123and   321abcor  213cba
1  abc321or123cbaand321cba   abc321or  123cbaand  321cba
```