# csv module not writing new line

Tags: python, excel, csv, openpyxl

I am working a script for reading specific cells from an Excel workbook into a list, and then from the list into a CSV.  There's a loop to get workbooks open from a folder as well.

My code:

```
import csv
import openpyxl
import os

path = r'C:\Users.....'  # Folder holding workbooks
workbooks = os.listdir(path)

cell_values = []  # List for storing cell values from worksheets

for workbook in workbooks:  # Workbook iteration
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(os.path.join(path, workbook), data_only=True)  # Open workbook
    sheet = wb.active  # Get sheet

    f = open('../record.csv', 'w', newline='')  # Open the CSV file
    cell_list = ["I9", "AK6", "N35"]  # List of cells to check

    with f:  # CSV writer loop
        record_writer = csv.writer(f)  # Open CSV writer

        for cells in cell_list:  # Loop through cell list to get cell values and write them to the cell_values list
            cell_values.append(sheet[cells].value)  # Append cell values to the cell_values list
        record_writer.writerow(cell_values)  # Write cell_values list to CSV

quit()  # Terminate program after all workbooks in the folder have been analyzed
```

The output just puts all values on the same line, albeit separated by commas, but it doesn't help me when I go to open my results in Excel if everything is on the same line.  When I was using `xlrd`, the format was vertical but all I had to do was transpose the dataset to be good. But I had to change from `xlrd` (which was a smart move in general) because it would not read merged cells.

I get this:

```
4083940,140-21-541,NP,8847060,140-21-736,NP
```

When I want this

```
4083940,140-21-541,NP
8847060,140-21-736,NP
```

Edit - I forgot the "what have I tried" portion of my post. I have tried changing my loops around to avoid overwriting the previous write to the CSV.  I have tried clearing the list on each loop to get the script to treat each new entry as a new line.  I have tried adding `\n` in the writer line as I saw in a couple of posts.  I have tried to use `writerows` instead of `writerow`.  I tried `A` instead of `W` even though it is a fix and not a solution but that didn't quite work right either.

Comment: Rather than posting your entire code, consider posting a stripped-down section that only performs the tasks you are having issues with. For example, if importing your workbooks isn't an issue, don't include it in your post.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I just wasnt sure if I had messed up somewhere prior to the loops or maybe nested incorrectly.  But I cut it down.

Comment: I think you've cut it too much! Basically, in order to help, someone would need an example of what data you are working with, what output you are getting, and what output you are wanting. But don't just post the input XLS file, bring the data as far as you can. As a guide, look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70539618/10245780 to see how much you should post.

Comment: You would think as many of these I have looked at the past day or so I wouldn't have derped it up but I made some edits that should help.  Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Your code has no way for python to know from which row a value originates, it simply reads values from cells into a list. It has no way to know where you want to break the line. Consider making a list per row, maybe in a dictionary, then writing out each row.

Comment: It's also still unclear what your input data is, so it's hard to give more specific help.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that others can run. Include a small sample of any input data needed to do so.

Comment: In your code you have only a single `record_writer.writerow(cell_values)` line - it's not within a loop. If you want multiple rows you need multiple writerow calls :)

Comment: Michael, you just gave me the logic Ive been overlooking.  I was able to put a quick fix in place by slicing the list inside of the writerow in three places to individually add the values.  It isn't practical for probably anything more than 3 cells but Im just glad to see the results I have been looking for and will work on a real fix next, now that I understand the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that `cell_values` is accumulating the cells from multiple sheets.  You need to reset it, like, `cell_values = []`, for every sheet.

I went back to your original example and:

- moved the opening of record.csv up, and placed all the work inside the scope of that file being open and written into
- moved `cell_values = []` inside your workbook loop
- moved `cell_list = ["I9", "AK6", "N35"]` to the top, because that's really scoped for the entire script, if every workbook has the same cells
- removed `quit()`, it's not necessary at the very end of the script, and in general should probably be avoided: [Python exit commands - why so many and when should each be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19747371/246801)

```py
import csv
import openpyxl
import os

path = r'C:\Users.....'  # Folder holding workbooks
workbooks = os.listdir(path)

cell_list = ["I9", "AK6", "N35"]  # List of cells to check 

with open('record.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    record_writer = csv.writer(f)

    for workbook in workbooks:
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(os.path.join(path, workbook), data_only=True)
        sheet = wb.active
        cell_values = []  # reset for every sheet

        for cells in cell_list:
            cell_values.append(sheet[cells].value)

        # Write one row per sheet
        record_writer.writerow(cell_values)
```

Also, I can see your new the CSV module, and struggling a little conceptually (since you tried `writerow`, then `writerows`, trying to debug your code).  Python's official document for CSV doesn't really give ***practical examples*** of how to use it.  Try reading up here, [Writing to a CSV](https://python-adv-web-apps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/csv.html#writing-to-a-csv).

Comment: Im going to edit and add my full 25 lines of code.  I had it up earlier because I wasn't sure how much other people would need but I was told it was too much.

Comment: I modified my answer based on your original code, you were pretty close.